# Parsing HTTP POST data to XML in BizTalk

Tags: schema, biztalk, biztalk-2010

how can I parse a POST data like this

ELEMENT1=12345&ELEMENT2=56789&ELEMENT3=9

or

{"ELEMENT1":"12345","ELEMENT2":"56789","ELEMENT3":"9"}

to

```
<ELEMENT1>12345</ELEMENT1>
<ELEMENT2>56789</ELEMENT2>
<ELEMENT3>9</ELEMENT3>
```

Where the element name comes from the POST data

The different POST data doesn't have to be in the same schema.

Comment: Version? 2010? 2013?

Comment: Yes you can, but it's not straight forward in 2010. In 2013 R2 it is a lot easier.  See http://blogs.biztalk360.com/consuming-json-endpoint-with-biztalk-2010-r2-rest-wcf-webhttp-adapter/